# How can I declare this struct which has an Optional error field?

Tags: rust

How can I declare this struct correctly?

[PLAYGROUND CODE](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=89cadd3f160a16811b2042948c04cb58)

```rust
use std::{error};

pub struct AppError {
  msg: Option<String>,
  // error: Option<anyhow::Error>, // This works
  error: Option<dyn error::Error + Send + Sync + 'static>, // but I need this, not anyhow
}
```

the error is:

```
error[E0277]: the size for values of type `(dyn std::error::Error + Send + Sync + 'static)` cannot be known at compilation time
 --> src/lib.rs:6:10
  |
6 |   error: Option<dyn error::Error + Send + Sync + 'static>, // but I need this, not anyhow
  |          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ doesn't have a size known at compile-time
  |
  = help: the trait `Sized` is not implemented for `(dyn std::error::Error + Send + Sync + 'static)`
note: required by a bound in `Option`

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0277`.
```

**How to fix this?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can wrap your error in a Box

```rs
use std::{error};

pub struct AppError {
  msg: Option<String>,
  // error: Option<anyhow::Error>, // This works
  error: Option<Box<dyn error::Error + Send + Sync + 'static>>, // but I need this, not anyhow
}
```

Comment: I choose this because is the first one. Thanks! Can you help me understand why this error now: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=1d8e9cf479b37055ec1d0263f1082779: `cannot move out of `*self` which is behind a mutable reference`?

Comment: I asked it here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73939469/what-is-the-best-value-to-return-from-this-method. Can you help me?

Comment: @FredHors Seems like you already got an answer ;).

Answer (score 1):

As the compiler tells you, the size of the error type cannot be determined at compile time. A possible solution would be to place the error on the heap and instead return a pointer:

```
use std::{error};

pub struct AppError {
  msg: Option<String>,
  // error: Option<anyhow::Error>, // This works
  error: Option<Box<dyn error::Error + Send + Sync + 'static>>, // but I need this, not anyhow
}
```