# What is the best value to return from this method?

Tags: rust

I'm using the below code for my own `AppError` custom struct.

[PLAYGROUND HERE](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=a943852aaf1abb8d4ef21fa1a5394451).

```rust
use std::{error};

pub struct AppError {
    msg: Option<String>,
    error: Option<Box<dyn error::Error + Send + Sync + 'static>>,
}

impl AppError {
    pub fn new_from_err<E: error::Error + Send + Sync + 'static>(error: E) -> Self {
        Self {
            msg: None,
            error: Some(Box::new(error)),
        }
    }

    pub fn add_msg(&mut self, msg: &str) -> Self {
        self.msg = Some(msg.to_string());

        *self
    }
}
```

As you can see I would like to return an instance of `AppError` from `pub fn add_msg()` method but I'm having this error instead:

```
error[E0507]: cannot move out of `*self` which is behind a mutable reference
  --> src/lib.rs:19:9
   |
19 |         *self
   |         ^^^^^ move occurs because `*self` has type `AppError`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0507`.
```

1. Is there a way to fix this?
2. Is there a batter way to return the instance of `AppError`, maybe a reference? I don't know what is better in a standard use in everyday code like:

```rust
match new_player_api_call.status() {
  StatusCode::CREATED => (),
  StatusCode::CONFLICT => {
      err = something();

      return Err(Error::new_from_err(err).add_msg("player already exists"));
  }
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to return a value, you have to own it.

```
pub fn add_msg(mut self, msg: &str) -> Self {
  self.msg = Some(msg.to_string());
  self
}
```

I've used this idiom as a builder pattern before. It's useful if you intend to construct these errors as `AppError::new_from_err(...).add_msg("...").add_msg("...")` and is a fairly typical builder design pattern.

If you *really* want to return the same mutable reference you just got, you can do that too.

```
pub fn add_msg(&mut self, msg: &str) -> &mut Self {
  self.msg = Some(msg.to_string());
  self
}
```

But this is, frankly, really weird Rust code. It takes a mutable reference and then gives it back, which is what the reference *would* have done anyway. So if you're going to take a `&mut self`, it makes far more sense to simply return nothing.

```
pub fn add_msg(&mut self, msg: &str) {
  self.msg = Some(msg.to_string());
}
```

Note that, internally, this returns `()`, the unit value of the unit type. But thanks to syntax sugar, you don't have to worry about that and can think of it as returning nothing at all.